# Combine Two Images Into A single One Using OpenCV using Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have two images that are mostly similar, but have some details that are different. I want to create a third image that has all the parts that are different together while keeping the one that are the same. For example, let's say I have a picture of a red circle to the left, and a blue triangle to the right, I want to create a picture that contains both a red circle to the left and a blue triangle to the right

I tried using `cv2.add` but it doesn't work, I tried using `cv2.addweighted` but it only works if the background of the image is black and I set the weights at `1`. How else can I make this work? Can I use another library instead of OpenCV to make my life easier?

This is my desired output:

[image]

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('RedCircle.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('BlueTriangle.png')
img3 = cv2.add(img1,img2)

cv2.imshow('res',img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

if I use this code I get a blank screen:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to write any Python to do this, you can just type an **ImageMagick** one-liner in the Terminal if that's an option?

Comment: Just add the two images together using cv2.add(left, right) where left and right are the two images you show. In future, please post separate images. That makes it easier for people to use your images. Post your code. cv2.add should work just fine if the two images are exactly the same shape and dtype.

Comment: if i do what you say and use cv2.add, it doesn't work and i get a blank image https://imgur.com/a/ncfeW8a

Comment: What is your platform?  Do you have the needed WEBP readers? Have you viewed your img1 and img2 to see that the image was read properly?

Comment: I'm coding in Python, img1 and img2 are read properly, the issue only happens when I use cv2.add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. Just simply adding won't work.

- Read the two input images
- Convert the second one to grayscale and threshold as a mask
- Do bitwise and using the mask on image 1
- Do bitwise and using the inverted mask on image 2
- Add the two masked images together
- Save the results

Image 1 (converted from webp to png for viewing):

[image]

Image 2 (converted from webp to png for viewing):

[image]

```
import cv2
 
img1 = cv2.imread('circle.webp')
print(img1.shape)

img2 = cv2.imread('triangle.webp')
print(img2.shape)

gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(gray2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

result1 = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask=thresh2)
result2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask=255-thresh2)
result = cv2.add(result1, result2)

cv2.imwrite("triangle_thresh.png", thresh2)
cv2.imwrite("circle_masked.png", result1)
cv2.imwrite("triangle_masked.png", result2)
cv2.imwrite("circle_triangle_combined.png", result)

cv2.imshow('img1',img1)
cv2.imshow('img2',img2)
cv2.imshow('thresh2',thresh2)
cv2.imshow('result1',result1)
cv2.imshow('result2',result2)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded triangle image:

[image]

Masked circle image:

[image]

Masked triangle image:

[image]

Combined masked images:

[image]